# sudo: command: command not found on CentOS 6

Tags: bash, centos6

### MVCE:

on `bash 4.1.2`, `Centos 6.10` (because we're monsters).

`sudo command vim`

returns

`sudo: command: command not found`

I don't understand why. on `bash 4.4.23`, `Mac OS High Sierra` it works as expected. It is very difficult to google this as people use "command" as a placeholder for various commands they are talking about.

### Actual problem:

I have a function (seen below) named `vim`, taking the `command` out from its calls to vim *doesn't* cause it to fail, like I'd expect, on both bash 4.4 and 4.1.

I have a function to automatically sudo vim if I can't write to file:

```
vim() {
    #only good for auto-sudo. delete if no sudo privileges.
    if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]; then
        command vim "$@"
    #cases: if we can write to the file, or the file doesn't exist but we can make new files in that dir
    elif [[ -w "$1" || ( -w $(dirname "$1") && ! -f "$1" ) ]]; then
        # \vim or 'vim' only escape aliases, not functions
        command vim "$1"
    else
        #this 'command' isn't required! It won't loop forever without it.
        sudo env HOME="$HOME" command vim -u $HOME/.vim/vimrc "$1"
    fi
}
```

I expect command to be required, since otherwise `vim` should refer to the function I made and call itself ad infinitum. However, not only is it *not* required, on both the CentOS and Mac systems, but also it causes the function to fail on the CentOS box!

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Is there a convenient bash changelog I can look at to know if "command" somehow wasn't implemented until after bash 4.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` expects an executable; `command` is (usually) a shell built-in, not an executable, that modifies how the shell performs its lookup. `sudo vim` would work fine, because `sudo` *can't* run a shell function or use an alias named `vim` that shadows the executable that `command vim` would give you.

`macOS` actually *does* provide a shell script `/usr/bin/command` which (as far as I can tell) appears to simulate the shell built-in while compensating for the case-insensitivity that HFS+ defaults to. The built-in `command` will shadow it in `bash`, but it would be available from other shells (or from commands that run other commands, like `sudo`).

---

POSIX requires that `command` be implemented, though not necessarily as a shell built-in. Providing a shell with `command` as a built-in is probably sufficient for the OS.  (The POSIX spec states "The command utility is most likely to be provided as a regular built-in.", and proceeds to list some reasons why `command` isn't listed among the other commands that *must* be built-ins.)

Comment: why does `sudo command vim` work on bash 4.4 on my Mac, then? Why couldn't sudo run a shell function named vim?

Comment: Just updated with an answer to that, as I was puzzled as well.

Comment: It also works on Centos 7, which also has /usr/bin/command. So, the builtin cannot be run by sudo, and neither can functions, but the executable `/usr/bin/command` can, which is why it works in the places it does?

Comment: Correct. It's most commonly implemented as a shell built-in, but it's only required to be *available* by the POSIX standard. As such, a POSIX-compliant OS needs to ensure it is available regardless of which shell is in use.

Comment: Your edit makes it sound like CentOS 6 is not POSIX-compliant, as it only provides a builtin, not an executable. Is that correct?

Comment: It's probably *mostly* POSIX-compliant, with the absence of an always-available `command` command a bug that prevents it from being *fully* compliant. Like I said, `command` is usually implemented by the shell (I'm not really aware of one that *doesn't*), so its absence wouldn't usually be missed (unless you tried to use it from `env`, as you did in your shell function).